# Rails how to pass id to custom controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

[image]I am new to rails and trying to figure out how to pass id from view to controller. I have create below routes.rb file i didnt want resources here just to have better understanding of how to pass params

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get 'sites/edit/:id', to: 'sites#edit'

  get 'sites/main'

  devise_for :users
  root 'sites#main'

  # For details on the DSL available within this file, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html
end
```

below is my controller

```
class SitesController < ApplicationController

  def main
    @site = Site.all
  end

  def edit
    @site = Site.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

  def site_params
    params.require(:site).permit(:title, :subtitle,:name)
  end
end
```

and i have two views for my site controller. In main.html.erb

```
<h1>Sites#main</h1>
<p><%= current_user.email %> user is signned in </p>

<%= @site.each do |temp| %>
  <p><%= temp.name %></p>
  <p></p>
  <p></p>

  <%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(@temp) %>
<% end %>
```

I am not able to link it to correct controller.

Comment: What is the problem ? Is there any `@temp` defined ? I guess you want to use only `temp`.

Comment: and just a tip: in rails `main` is called `index`.

Comment: Can you please post the result of `rake routes`

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace

```
<%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(@temp) %>
```

to

```
<%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(temp) %>
```

You have the variable `temp` not `@temp`

Also, As `sarcastic` suggested you need to change the route entry to

```
get 'sites/edit/:id', to: 'sites#edit', as: :sites_edit
```

Comment: i try this <%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(temp) %>
 but not working updated see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VsgU.png

Comment: Change your route to "get 'sites/:id/edit', to: 'sites#edit', as: :sites_edit"

Comment: Yes, that will do

Answer (score 0):

First: your edit routes should not be

`get 'sites/edit/:id', to: 'sites#edit'`

Instead it should be `get 'sites/:id/edit' => 'sites#edit'`

Second: your link to method should not be

`<%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(@temp) %>`

instead it should be `<%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(temp) %>`

You can get to know about your routes from terminal by doing **rake routes** or If you want a browser view then

> http://localhost:3000/rails/info/routes

Comment: i try this <%= link_to "Edit Site", sites_edit_path(temp) %>
 but not working updated see this https://i.stack.imgur.com/1VsgU.png